# Passing arguments to init in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How can I pass arguments to `init()` or access the arguments passed to `create()` inside `init()` in ember.js

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just use `this.get('theProperty')`

**Example:**

```
var data = {
    foo: "hello",
};

var MyModel = Em.Object.extend({
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        var foo = this.get('foo');
        alert(foo);
    }
});

MyModel.create(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use closures and create a new init function that passes the closed argument to its prototype init function. Also, this way you don't end up overwriting sensitive properties, like methods for example.
note: init is called after all the properties are set by the constructor

```
Class = Ember.Object.extend({
 init:function(response){
  console.log(this.get("msg")+this.get("msg_addressee")+"?");
  console.log(response);
 },
 msg:"SUP, "
});

var arg = "not much.";

obj = Class.create({
 init:function(){
  console.log("output:");
  this._super(arg);
  console.log("indeed, "+arg);
 },
 msg_addressee:"dude"
});

//output:
//SUP, dude?
//not much.
//indeed, not much.
```