# New EmberJS .on('init') idiom and inheritance

Tags: ember.js

I've been told to use .on('init') instead of overriding init(), to avoid issues synchronizing bindings and aliases. However, I'm not sure how to handle ordering of dispatch in inheritance with this pattern.

I used to do:

```
var Superclass = Ember.Object.extend({
    init: function () { /* ... */ }
});

var Subclass = Superclass.extend({
    init: function () {
        // Init superclass first...
        this._super();

        /* ... */
    }
});
```

But I'm not sure how to properly do this with the .on('init') idiom: How do I ensure the superclass is initialization is called BEFORE the subclass?

- It seems that if I call both superclass and sub-class .on('init') functions "onInit", only the sub-class version will be called. This means that I have to invent new versions of the name (which is already useless and doesn't need a name....) for each new sub-class?
- I could alternately ALWAYS use the name, onInit, say, and use this._super() as before, but I'm worried that this semantic may not be guarateed and could break at any time?

Here's a JSFiddle illustrating the issues and questions I'm encountering:

http://jsfiddle.net/9fctF/2/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing arguments to init in ember.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951513/passing-arguments-to-init-in-ember-js)